# Problems with Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.5, psql 10.4 and pgAdmin 1.22.2

Tags: python3, postgresql, pgadmin

Code did run with:

Lubuntu 16.10, Python 3.5.2 (python3), psql 9.5.7 and pgAdmin 1.22.1. .... 
Also installed:
Python 2.7.12 (python)

Code does not run with:

Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.5 (python and python3), psql 10.4 and pgAdmin 1.22.2.

Extensions:
Installed extensions in virtualenv with the same version.

Error Message:
Now it gives the following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/myname/Documents/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 699, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/home/myname/Documents/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 593, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/home/myname/Documents/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 528, in __init__
    self.socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
  File "/home/myname/Documents/projectname/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 450, in wrap_socket
    ssl_version=self._protocol, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1149, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

at some point you're giving it ssl key file (.pem|.crt|.key) which are not found, go over your configuration and check for a path to ssl keys. maybe somewhere in your configuration you need to enter whether you want to use ssl or not, and it's accidentally set to 'true'.

you can either use valid certificates, or cancel ssl.